# Does tikz 2.1 no longer work with the preview package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvi, preview

I used to be able to create png images of diagrams made with tikz code by using the preview package and printing the dvi output from dvips to a png file using ghostscript. The latest version of tikz seems to have broken this ability in some way.

If I use the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds,patterns,matrix,shapes,fit,calc,shadows,plotmarks}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I then run Latex to get the dvi file, and dvips to convert to postscript. I then run ghostscript to produce the png with the following command:

```
gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=png16m -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r300 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dSAFER -q -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="tikz_preview_png_problem.png" -f "tikz_preview_png_problem.ps"
```

Previous to tikz 2.1 this worked fine, but now produces the following output:

```
Error: /undefined in pgfo
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   fa
lse   1   %stopped_push   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_
pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   1755   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval-
-   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringv
al--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1161/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:74/200(L)--   --dict:95
/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 9094
GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Is there any way to get around this, it's a pain in the bum as I liked to be able to produce high res png of my vector graphics for use in non-latex docs or websites etc. I'm using Miktex on windows with Texniccenter as my editor in case it is relevant.

Comment: Why are you not just using `pdflatex` instead? It works fine and also allows you to convert to PNG. Have a look at the `standalone` class which is helpful here. The upcoming version will have an option to convert the output to a PNG automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the standalone package as an alternative, I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @crobar: The `standalone` class uses the `preview` package internally, so it just reduces the code overhead, but won't save you from the ghostscript error.

Comment: Tikz has nothing to do with this error. I think the problem comes from preview and ghostscript. On OS X, I can compile with dvips but with the  Apple distiller, if the distiller is  ghostscript I have the same problem with the stack.

Comment: @Altermundus: TikZ could have something to do with the error. If I swap `tikzpicture` for `tabular` or even a PSTricks `pspicture` everything rolls along smoothly.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I think I'll just fall back on the old "make the pdf, take a screenshot zoomed in on the image, paste into paint and cut out the diagram" method, which I used before I discovered my current method, until they fix tikz/dvips/ghostscript. I don't really do it often enough to warrant a lot of investigation at the minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I poked around a bit and I couldn't figure out what is going wrong with the Postscript pipeline. My preferred method of generating standalone images uses the PDF pipeline along with ImageMagick's `convert` utility. The workflow is considerably simpler:

```
pdflatex foo.tex
convert -density 300 foo.pdf foo.png
```

Windows binaries can be found [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), but there are two caveats:

- You will need `gswin32c.exe` on your `PATH` as `convert` requires GhostScript to get images out of PDF or PS format.
- `convert.exe` will have to be before Windows binaries on the `PATH` as there is a system32 tool also called `convert.exe` that shares the same name. Or you will have to rename `convert.exe` to something like `imconvert.exe`.

The [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com) is a nifty tool that can help you sort the Windows `PATH`.

---

### Update

It appears there was indeed a change in TikZ 2.10 that broke compatibility with Preview on the Postscript side. There [are](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3153846&group_id=142562&atid=752792) [two](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3112189&group_id=142562&atid=752792) prior bug reports that reference this problem and [a post on the PGF mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/Pgf-2.10-and-preview-latex-td30717762.html) that pins the problem down to a line in `pgfsys-dvips.def`.

---

### Update 2

Since the problem is with TikZ producing broken Postscript and not with GhostScript, then `gswin32c` should be able to perform the conversion on a PDF file:

```
pdflatex foo.tex
gswin32c -sDEVICE=png16m -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r300 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dSAFER -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=foo.png foo.pdf
```

This would spare the installation and setup of ImageMagick.

Comment: Thanks, I think this does in fact answer my question, so I'll mark it as the answer. I will look into your suggested workaround, but as I work on multiple computers would prefer something easier to implement.

Comment: @crobar It is possible to use your GhostScript command line on a PDF file instead of a PS file. I just instinctively reach for ImageMagick because I always have it installed and the required command is a *lot* simpler.