# Transparency in tikz, preview package and xelatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, preview, transparency

Is it possible to have transparency in a tikz picture while using the `preview` package and compiling with xelatex?

The following mwe compiles without warnings/errors  under both xelatex and pdflatex but with xelatex there is no transparency. Everything is printed opaque. With pdflatex everything works as expected.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[xetex,active,tightpage]{preview}
%\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}

\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1ex]
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,1);
  \filldraw [fill=red,draw opacity=0.5] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the same here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17080/does-tikz-2-1-no-longer-work-with-the-preview-package

Comment: There is an issue with XeLaTeX, `preview` package and TikZ shadings, most likely also with patterns and transparency. I as `standalone` class author, which uses `preview`, got contacted by a user two month ago because of it. I tracked it down to the above combination. The user then wrote an email to the `preview` author, but I didn't heard anything about it ever since.

Comment: @Martin, I see. I'll send an email to the author too. I hope it is something easily fixed.

Comment: it also might be an issue of PGF/TikZ instead. Anyway it seems only to appear with XeLaTeX+`preview`+some feature of PGF/TikZ (shadings, patterns, transparency). It works without `preview` or with it under `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Martin, Just removing the preview package outputs the expected result even with xelatex. So I don't think it is related with xelatex or/and pgf (of course I can be wrong). AFAIK Tikz's patterns problems are related with xelatex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid the issue by selecting the page size to be equal to the picture size. Therefore you don't need `preview` and it works fine with XeLaTeX. For this you need to save the picture in a box register. Because `geometry` only allows to select the page size in the preamble you need to move the picture there, which is OK as long it inside a savebox (like inside a `lrbox` environment).

I'm planning to build a feature like this into `standalone` as an alternative to `preview`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}

%\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
%\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
%\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}

\pagestyle{empty}
\normalfont% required to select normal font already in the preamble
\begin{lrbox}{0}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1ex]
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,1);
  \filldraw [fill=red,draw opacity=0.5] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{lrbox}

\geometry{paperwidth=\wd0,paperheight=\ht0,margin=0cm}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\usebox{0}%
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

(The outer dark frame is the background of the PDF viewer)

---

The upcoming version 1.0 of `standalone` includes code similar to this and avoids the need of `preview`. It should work fine for XeLaTeX.

Comment: The fill color (red) is still opaque. I cannot see the black line inside the red rectangle. Herbert's answer can be used as a reference.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist: That's simple because `draw opacity` was used (by the OP, so I did the same). If you replace it by `fill opacity` or `opacity` (which does both) the filled rectangle will be transparent.

Answer (score 3):

if I use PSTricks and `XeLaTeX` together with preview, it works. The reason why I suppose a problem with TikZ and not preview

[image]

Comment: I sent an email to preview's author (no answer so far) and filled a bug report for tikz https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3322397&group_id=142562&atid=752792

Comment: I cannot produce PSTricks transparency with XeLaTeX, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38001/9467.