# preview and standalone crop too much of tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, preview, crop, standalone

When I try to fit the page size to my tikz image, too much is cropped. No matter whether I use `\documentclass{standalone}`, `\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}` or `\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}`. The complete source:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[color=lightgray]
        \draw (-8,0) -- (8,0);
        \filldraw[shift={(8,0)},scale=0.25] +(-210:1) -- +(210:1) -- +(0:1) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,-8) -- (0,8);
        \filldraw[shift={(0,8)},scale=0.25,rotate=90] +(-210:1) -- +(210:1) -- +(0:1) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \newcommand\hyper[4][]{\draw[mark=*,mark options={fill=black}] plot [#1] ({#2*exp(#4)+#3*exp(-#4)}, {#2*exp(#4)-#3*exp(-#4)})}
    \newcommand\hyperline[6]{\draw ({#1*exp(#3)+#2*exp(-#3)}, {#1*exp(#3)-#2*exp(-#3)}) -- ({#4*exp(#6)+#5*exp(-#6)}, {#4*exp(#6)-#5*exp(-#6)})}
    \pgfsetplotmarkrepeat{6}
    \foreach \a in {-1, 1}{%
        \foreach \b in {-1, 1}{%
            \begin{scope}[very thin, color=gray]
                \begin{scope}[domain=-2:2]
                    \hyper\a0\x;
                    \hyper0\b\x;
                    \hyper\a\b\x;
                \end{scope}
                \begin{scope}[domain=-1.3:1.3]
                    \hyper{\a*2}{\b*2}\x;
                \end{scope}
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
    \begin{scope}[color=darkred]
        \foreach \k in {0,...,2}{%
            \hyperline0{-1}\k1{-1}\k;
            }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

After reading [Transparency in tikz, preview package and xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21011/transparency-in-tikz-preview-package-and-xelatex), I tried to set the size manually:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=163mm,paperheight=163mm,margin=0mm}
```

But this gives me the error message:

> ! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too
>   short.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, solved the problem with `standalone`. It was the empty line after the `tikzpicture` environment. Like meantioned here: [Standalone package creates a page with a fixed width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34590/standalone-package-creates-a-page-with-a-fixed-width)

And the following makes it work with `preview`. Notice that it is loaded after `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

The last problem is because the `minimal` class does not work with `geometry`. Simply using the `article` class made that work too. (See also [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class))

Comment: In `preview`, `\PreviewBorder=<length>\relax` is the replacement for the `border=<length>` of `standalone` document class.