# Problem with preview package (and standalone class) with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I updated MacTeX recently with TeX Live Manager and I  installed the last `tikz/pgf` CVS (02/12/2011) and I got a problem with the `standalone` class. The size of the picture seems fine but nothing is drawn.
I don't know if it's possible to find a workaround. I compiled the next code with `latex` no problem with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill] (0,0)rectangle(5,5); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill] (0,0)rectangle(5,5); 
 \end{tikzpicture} 
  % or  \tikz \draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
  % or  \tikz{\draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5)} % with pgf 2.10 cvs
\end{document}
```

The log file gives :

> This is dvips(k) 5.991 Copyright 2011 Radical Eye Software
>   (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2011.12.12:0630' -> standalone.ps .
>   [1](http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html) Error: /undefined in pgfo Operand stack: Execution stack:
>   %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
>   2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false
>   1 %stopped_push 1894 1 3 %oparray_pop 1893 1 3 %oparray_pop 1877 1 3
>   %oparray_pop 1771 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop
>   .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2
>   %stopped_push --nostringval-- Dictionary stack:
>   --dict:1154/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:81/200(L)-- --dict:100/300(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: 2 Current file position is 9241 GPL Ghostscript 9.02: Unrecoverable
>   error, exit code 1

If you want the `tikz/pgf` CVS package with pgfmanual_cvs.pdf, you can find it [here](http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html).

Comment: I can compile `\tikz \draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);` but not `\tikz{\draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5)}`.

Comment: `\tikz{\draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5)}` compiles with `article class` and I've the same problem with `\tikz \draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);`. Do you make a try with the last pgf cvs ? Perhaps my problem comes from the last version of MacTeX !

Comment: I used old pgf/tikz. Please try using `preview` package and `article` class to diagnose whether the error is caused by `preview` encapsulated in `standalone` class.

Comment: FWIW, Miktex compiles with `\tikz \draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);` and also with (notice the semicolon location!) `\tikz {\draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);} ` and shows two black squares as intended.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist The problem is not with pgf cvs but with MacTeX and some of the new tools. I updated my distribution yesterday. For the syntax `\tikz{\draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5)}`I was also surprised but with pgf CVS, the code compiles with another class. But `\tikz \draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);`is preferable !

Comment: @percusse The problem is not from the syntax; `\tikz{\draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5)} ` is fine only with pgf 2.1 version CVS but with the new preview package or the standalone class. pgf 2.1 cvs is not also the problem because I have the bad result with the official pgf. The culprit seems to be `preview package`

Comment: I'm stupid. I saw `This is dvips(k) 5.991` but I did not react. After some tests, I kept my editor with in the preferences :`latex`. The problem is not with `pdflatex`but with `dvips ...`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does tikz 2.1 no longer work with the preview package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17080/does-tikz-2-1-no-longer-work-with-the-preview-package)

Comment: @Altermundus: The upcoming v1.0 of standalone provides an alternative to `preview` which will be enabled by default. You can test the beta version, see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=2621195#2621195.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PostScript prologue is missing in fact of the special handling of `\AtBeginDocument` and `\special{ps::}` by `tikz`. If you reload it by "hand" it will work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}  

\begin{document}
\ifpdf
\else
  \special{ps::
    /pgfsc{}bind def% stroke color is empty by default
    /pgffc{}bind def% fill color is empty by default
    /pgfstr{stroke}bind def%
    /pgffill{fill}bind def%
    /pgfeofill{eofill}bind def%
    /pgfe{a dup 0 rlineto exch 0 exch rlineto neg 0 rlineto closepath}bind def% rectangle
    /pgfw{setlinewidth}bind def% setlinewidth
    /pgfs{save pgfpd 72 Resolution div 72 VResolution div neg scale 
      magscale{1 DVImag div dup scale}if 
      pgfx neg pgfy neg translate pgffoa .setopacityalpha}bind def% save
    /pgfr{pgfsd restore}bind def %restore
    userdict begin%
    /pgfo{pgfsd /pgfx currentpoint /pgfy exch def def @beginspecial}bind def %open
    /pgfc{newpath @endspecial pgfpd}bind def %close
    /pgfsd{globaldict /pgfdelta /delta where {pop delta} {0} ifelse put}bind def% save delta
    /pgfpd{/delta globaldict /pgfdelta get def}bind def % put delta
    /.setopacityalpha where {pop} {/.setopacityalpha{pop}def} ifelse % install .setopacityalpha 
    /.pgfsetfillopacityalpha{/pgffoa exch def
      /pgffill{gsave pgffoa .setopacityalpha fill 1 .setopacityalpha newpath fill grestore newpath}bind def
      /pgfeofill{gsave pgffoa .setopacityalpha eofill 1 .setopacityalpha newpath eofill grestore newpath}bind def}bind def
    /.pgfsetstrokeopacityalpha{/pgfsoa exch def /pgfstr{gsave pgfsoa .setopacityalpha stroke grestore newpath}bind def}bind def
    /pgffoa 1 def
    /pgfsoa 1 def
    end
  }
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill] (0,0)rectangle(5,5); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I could make `standalone` add this code automatically if `preview` is used in PS mode. What do you think?

Comment: @MartinScharrer: It  is a good idea if you add the code that is extracted from relevant PGF prologue file (rather than hard coding it) so any future changes in the prologue file can be available automatically in `standalone`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is now to use the `crop` option of `standalone` which does not use the `preview` package but crops the content using custom code. This works for DVI/PS and PDF output. Note that this option is available since v1.0 of `standalone` and is now the default (!), while before the `preview` option was the default.

Your original MWE therefore works fine with `standalone` v1.0 (as long the `preview` option is not re-enabled):

```
\documentclass{standalone}% works fine with v1.0
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill] (0,0)rectangle(5,5); 
 \end{tikzpicture} 
  % or  \tikz \draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
  % or  \tikz{\draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (5,5)} % with pgf 2.10 cvs
\end{document}
```