# psfrag + tcolorbox + tikz + eps + pdflatex = Error: /undefined in pgfo

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, eps, psfrag

Minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \psfrag{C0}[Bc][bl][1.5]{\mybox{$x$}}
   \includegraphics{empty.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(the content of `empty.eps` doesn't matter). Attempting to compile this with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape mwe.tex
```

leads to the following error:

```
Error: /undefined in pgfo
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:962/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:128/200(L)--   --dict:179/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 138771
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
system returned with code 256
```

What's amiss here?

P.S.: This [TikZ and auto-pst-pdf break Ghostscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166623/tikz-and-auto-pst-pdf-break-ghostscript) seems to be related.

Comment: You want to use a `tcolorbox`  as replacement text in a `.eps` file? Compilation works for me with `xelatex`, however

Comment: Yes, I want. In fact I did, meaning that this worked with `pdflatex` for at least some version (on a computer that's now broken).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37982/problem-with-preview-package-and-standalone-class-with-tikz?r=SearchResults&s=2|34.4999